# Give focus to a textbox after a node is selected in treeview

Tags: c#, textbox, focus

When I try to set focus by calling the `textBox1.Focus()` method on TreeView AfterSelect event, the TextBox is not selected.
If I write `textBox1.Focus()` on textBox1 Leave event it works. How I can do it more correctly? Why focus is being lost?

Comment: Add some code ... we are not wizards ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the focus to your textbox in treeview Enter event.

Your code doesn't work because AfterSelect event is raised before treeview is really focused.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the SelectedNode Property of the TreeView control to Nothing and then set the focus to the TextBox. Just like here:

```
Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterSelect
    TreeView1.SelectedNode = Nothing
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub
```

The downside of this is that you don't see which Node of the TreeView was clicked. I don't know if you can live with that.